# memory access violation error - 0xC0000005

Tags: c++

I got memory access violation error sometimes....

but I don't know where the error comes from...

So I reviewed the code and I found some strange code...

```
delete m_p1;
A *a = new A();
a->b = *c;
m_p1 = a; --> strange code.
```

I think it's a little strange line.... can i use the m_p1 after delete the m_p1?

It can make some memory access error??

Comment: You'll need to post more of the code

Comment: Post more of the code. You can use m_p1 even after delete, if you assign some valid value to it.

Comment: Use a debugger to find whereabouts the error occurs.

Comment: Show us a sample that crashes; I cannot find any problems in the code snippet above

Comment: Is m_p1 pointing to "this" pointer of the current A class instance, and in the same time m_p1 is a member of the A class? This would explain something...

Answer (score 10):

### Debugging a memory access violation

You're on Windows.

This means that if the error happens on a machine with Visual Studio installed, you'll have an option to open it to debug the error and thus know the *exact* line where the error happens.

### Studying the code

Too little code to answer correctly. Still, one can guess:

```
delete m_p1;
```

Are you sure m_p1 is a pointer to a valid object ? (allocated with `new`, etc.)

```
A *a = new A();
```

You must review the constructor for A. Perhaps it does something wrong.

```
a->b = *c;
```

This is the line I  suspect the more : If `c` is an invalid pointer (either NULL, or points to some random address), dereferencing it to put the result inside `a->b` could provoke the error

```
m_p1 = a; --> strange code.
```

The funny fact is that this is the only line of code which **can't** produce the error you got : a is a pointer containing an address, and you can copy addresses around. It's using this address (dereferencing the pointer, etc.) that causes memory access violation.

### About `m_p1 = a;`

This code is not so strange, but it proves you still have issues with pointers.

In C, C++, Java, etc., when you allocate a memory (to put things inside, to create an object, etc.), the allocator (new, malloc, whatever...) will give you a *handle*. In Java/C#, this is called a reference, and in C/C++, this is a pointer.

Let's imagine you'll want to go to a concert, and the *seat number* is where you'll sit, and the `seat` is the real object, where you'll sit and enjoy the show.

- `m_p1` is a paper in your wallet where you want to have exact *seat number*
- `a` is a temporary paper, a napkin, whatever...
- `delete m_p1` is when you resell your place, so the seat number you bought before is not valid anymore. You should not use it anymore.
- `a = new A()` is when you buy another place, so you have in `a` another valid seat number, but for whatever reason, instead of writing in in your wallet (`m_p1`), you'll write it on a napkin.
- `m_p1 = a` is when you eventually copy the seat number from some napkin to your wallet.

The point is that you have:

- pointers, which contains memory addresses (the pointer value)
- memory addresses, where you have real objects

Destroying a real object through `delete` won't destroy the pointer. It only makes the address invalid (the address didn't change. It's just not valid anymore). So you can put in a pointer whatever address you want, even reuse the pointer to contain the address of another object.

Answer (score 4):

What's strange about it? m_p1 is a pointer, and the line in question is assigning another pointer to it. Perfectly legal C++. The code is not C though, so I've removed that tag.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what platform you're on, there are tools to help you find these kind of problems.

First, if you get a memory access violation problem, you should be able to get something like a core file (in the unix world at least, I'm sure it is called something entirely different on Windows). 
From that, you should be able to see exactly where the violation happened.

There are also some tools that will help you both with static analysis of your code and runtime checking for memory violations.

coverity, purify and valgrind are a few examples that comes to mind.

If you're on windows, this might be helpful: [how can I debug an access violation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6decc55h%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

`delete m_p1` means "m_p1 points to something that was allocated with new in the past. Please get rid of it". It does *not* mean "please get rid of the pointer m_p1".

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to resurrect this "thread".

An access violation often comes when we try to access or delete already-freed memory. The trick is ; when you know the memory address where the access violation occurs your can create a **data breakpoint** and wait until it get triggered. After that it will reveal you **where** and **when** this memory has been freed or modified.